# Radio button wardrobe malfunction with Angular powered Bootstrap

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

When placing Angular powered Bootstrap radio buttons as per [the example](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/buttons/examples), the buttons look ok. But if the element with the **btn-group-toggle** class isn't the immediate parent, the buttons suddenly display the radio button nipple, as shown in the picture below. How can I layout non-mammalian radio buttons in nested elements?

[image: Radio buttons]

The html template:

```html
<table class="table">
  <tr class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" ngbRadioGroup>
    <th>Numbers</th>
    <th *ngFor="let month of [1,2,3,4]">
      <label ngbButtonLabel class="btn btn-primary">
        <input ngbButton type="radio" [value]="month" />{{month}}
      </label>
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>

<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" ngbRadioGroup>
  <label ngbButtonLabel class="btn btn-primary" *ngFor="let month of [1,2,3,4]">
    <input ngbButton type="radio" [value]="month" />{{month}}
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: off-topic. Love the title with **wardrobe malfunction** :D

Comment: I don't know if there's something wrong with the Angular powered Bootstrap CSS, but simply having display:none for the input-element takes care of the problem.